# append table inside div

Tags: jquery

Hello am trying to add a table to a div but firebug gives me this error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal [Break On This Error] $('#news-tweets').append('

This is the code am running:

```
            for (var i in array) {
                var location = array[i].location;
                var user = array[i].user;
                var date = array[i].date;
                var profile_img = array[i].profile_img;
                var text = array[i].text;
                var url = array[i].url;
                show_tweets(user,date,profile_img,text,url);
                geocode(user, date, profile_img, text, url, location);
            }
            function show_tweets(user, date, profile_img, text, contentString){
                $('#news-tweets').append('<table width="320" border="1">
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">"+user+"</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="118">"+profile_img+"</td>
                  <td width="186">"+text+"</td>
                </tr>
              </table>');
                }
```

it shows me that I have an error right before

Comment: The problem is with you quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function show_tweets(user, date, profile_img, text, contentString)
{
    $('#news-tweets').append('<table width="320" border="1"><tr><td colspan="2" rowspan="1">' + user + '</td></tr><tr><td width="118">' + profile_img + '</td><td width="186">' + text + '</td></tr></table>');
}
```

Comment: no still doesn't work . it gives me error for the first apostrophe before <table...